UK change of signature
In the UK, is there a legal procedure for "officially" changing one's signature, or do people just start using a different signature? For example, new UK passports require the bearer to sign the passport. Can the bearer just start using a new signature thenceforth?
EDIT
To clarify, I mean changing the actual letters, not just the style. Changing it from one type of script to another, even. (For example, Chinese to English, or Greek to Russian.)

Doesn’t a signature change all the time even when you are not trying to change it?

@JoeW mine hasn't in about 30 years

@TigerGuy From my understanding at least in the US credit cards moved away from signatures for verification because they can and do change each time someone signs depending on the condition and are not reliable.

@JoeW That signature field on credit cards is nearly impossible to write clearly in. I don't have a legible signature, but if I did I doubt I could reproduce it on a CC.

@Barmar That isn't the only way that a signature is validated for credit card transactions and they also keep track of them at the credit card company when they can.

Most places that ask for your signature don't even have something to compare with, so there's no way to tell that it changed (my bank used to check this when I used the safe deposit box, but they stopped years ago). I think the general expectation is that you will check the signature if you claim a fraudulent activity was done in your name. So any signature you recognize can be used.
